# datepicker jquery returns incorrect date spring mvc

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, spring-mvc

I am running in weird issue from morning.

I am using jquery datepicker to get date field on my jsp page.

my application is based on spring mvc.

after user selects date on jsp page and submitting page , in controller i am not getting date what is selected by user , instead getting some different (future BST) date !

below is sample of my code  :

```
<script src="<c:url value="js2/jquery-1.9.1.js"/>"></script>
      <script src="<c:url value="js2/jquery-ui.js"/>"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

          $(function() {
                $( "#startDate" ).datepicker();
      });
</script>
```

and below is my field

```
<td class="pdngBtm7px"><form:input id="startDate"  name="startDate" path="startDate" />
```

once selecting todays date and submitting form to spring controller i am getting date in BST which is future date +2 years !

If anyone know this issue, please reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the format of the date submitted to controller is in the expected correct format for the controller mapping.

Or that your conversion service for dates is set up correctly to handle whatever you are submitting.

Comment: Thanks for reply. you are right actually :). I figured out that the field mapping used in jsp was of type java.utils.Date and jquery submits string format.  So i had to change the  path field mapping to String type instead of "Date" and in controller i am used date formatter to map string to Date again!   It was stupid issue i know , but this is what happen when you play with others code !